# How does Qt paint the painter path

Tags: c++, qt, qpainter, qpainterpath

The hierarchy of classes in Qt (5.4 version) is awesome. I tried to find solution in Qt's sources, but my end point of investigation is the `QPaintEngine`. This class has member:

```
virtual void QPaintEngine::drawPath(const QPainterPath &)
```

This member is simple gap (do nothing). The only derived class is  `QRasterPaintEngine` (implementation for linux), which does not override the `drawPath` method. Does somebody have ideas?

I want to find way to paint path. I guess that painter path (simplified version (without self intersections)) are converted to polygons. Given polygons are triangulated. I want to see implementation of triangulation.

Comment: I think it just forwards to the native drawer

Comment: Why? for example, qt allows to paint with usage Opengl. ( i guess  it uses the above algorithm of painting )

Comment: There is [`QPaintEngineEx`](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtbase/source/9754e5a03e4444a18ec7ca1525d196326ff4e038:src/gui/painting/qpaintengineex.cpp) which derives from `QPaintEngine`. Might be more, you need to dig deeper.

Comment: Thank you, i will try. I guess this class is private implementation. Documentation shows the only class QRasterPaintEngine (or i forgot something).

Comment: Polygon triangulation is a typical technique for 3D rendering, but Qt is much more 2D oriented. I would not assume it uses triangles.

Comment: I do not agree with you. 2D triangulation is common practise for rendering

Comment: but not for lines, there pixel based algorithms are better/faster

Comment: Yes, of course)) but I meant rendering of  complex shapes))

Comment: even then, Most of the QPainterPath primitives have efficient pixel based algorithms

Comment: I am interesting filling of path offsetting))

Comment: Have you tried stepping into the source code with the debugger? That would be the best way to see what happens IMO.

Comment: I tried)) i had some problems - i cannot step into QT source code from my debugger